# C# How to shorten Datagridview Selectionchanged code in a clean and proper way of coding

Tags: c#, winforms

I always wanted my code to be cleaner and readable. I'm here in order to achieve that. Since i'm a beginner, it's better to learn this early. Like calling all of them in a class, I don't want too see these many codes in my form. I hope someone would be able to give me a suggestions and a proper way of doing these.

Here's my code

```
 public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
{
    ADDSupplier supply;
    ADDPReturns returns;
    public SIMSSupplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public DataTable dbdataset;
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public string ID = "SPPLR-000";
    public int DeliveryID, OrderID, ReturnID;
    DataView db;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void Supplierview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = Supplierview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        SupplierID.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        CompanyName.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        ContactName.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ContactNumber.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Date.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Address.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        Remarks.Text = Supplierview.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

    }
    private void PurchaseOrder_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = PurchaseOrder.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        txt_purchase.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txt_supplier.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txt_item.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txt_date.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txt_quantity.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txt_cost.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txt_amount.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txt_sales.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        txt_code.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        txt_patient.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    }
    private void PurchaseDeliveries_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = PurchaseDeliveries.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        PurchaseID.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Supplier.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        ItemDescription.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Dates.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Quantity.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Unitcost.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        Amount.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        SalesInvoice.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        Codeitems.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        Patientname.Text = PurchaseDeliveries.Rows[row].Cells[9].Value.ToString();

    }
    private void PurchaseReturn_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var row = PurchaseReturn.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        txt_return.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txt_rsupplier.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txt_ritem.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txt_rmodel.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txt_rsrp.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txt_rcode.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txt_rdate.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txt_rremarks.Text = PurchaseReturn.Rows[row].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! SO is for problems. As your code works fine, I suggests you to ask this question on [this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i think you should learn to use Databinding, this could be done cleaner using it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview

Answer (score 1):

the first can simplify as the following:

```
private void Supplierview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = Supplierview.CurrentRow;
    SupplierID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    CompanyName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    ContactName.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    ContactNumber.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Date.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    Address.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    Remarks.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
}
```

the second , i would recommend use objects collection as a datasource for your grid. For example :

```
class DataItem{
    public string SupplierID {get;set;}
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
    .....
}

Supplierview.DataSource = "collection of DataItem"
```

then

```
private void Supplierview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataItem;
    if (dataItem != null)
    {
        SupplierID.Text = dataItem.SupplierID;
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using DataBinding for this, then there is no code needed to perform the actions in your sample.
If you dont want to use databinding you could simply make use of private methods to organize your code.
For example

```
#region Supplier Stuff

private void SupplierViewChanged(DataRow row)
{
    SupplierID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    CompanyName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    ContactName.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    ContactNumber.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    Date.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    Address.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
    Remarks.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();    
}

// put all other helper methods that deal with Supplier here...

#endregion Supplier Stuff


private void Supplierview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SupplierViewChanged(Supplierview.CurrentRow);
}
```

This makes your code a bit more organized and readable, but databinding is still the method I would choose